# Validation allow only number and characters in searchview for search

Tags: android

In search box how to validate user only search with character and number not allowed for entering special character.

Comment: Check with regex before searching.

Comment: In keyboard we can't restrict.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this. But still they able to entry number by long press on the top row in the keyboard

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
  ...
  android:inputType="text" />
```